# Pytorch: How to unflatten/get back the network from flattened network?

Tags: python, pytorch, flatten

I am using the following function to flatten the network:

```
#############################################################################
# Flattening the NET
#############################################################################
def flattenNetwork(net):
    flatNet = []
    shapes = []
    for param in net.parameters():
        #if its WEIGHTS
        curr_shape = param.cpu().data.numpy().shape
        shapes.append(curr_shape)
        if len(curr_shape) == 2:
            param = param.cpu().data.numpy().reshape(curr_shape[0]*curr_shape[1])
            flatNet.append(param)
        elif len(curr_shape) == 4:
            param = param.cpu().data.numpy().reshape(curr_shape[0]*curr_shape[1]*curr_shape[2]*curr_shape[3])
            flatNet.append(param)
        else:
            param = param.cpu().data.numpy().reshape(curr_shape[0])
            flatNet.append(param)
    finalNet = []
    for obj in flatNet:
        for x in obj:
            finalNet.append(x)
    finalNet = np.array(finalNet)
    return finalNet,shapes
```

The above function returns all the weights as a `numpy` column vector `finalNet` and `shapes` (list) of the network. I want to see the effect of weight modifications on the prediction accuracy. So, I change the weights. How can I copy this modified weight vector back to the original network? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between model definition (its `forward` function), and the parameter configuration (what's called model state, and is easily accessible as a dictionary using [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict)).

You can get a model's state, as you did with your implementation `flattenNetwork`.  However reverting this operation (*i.e.* if you only have the weights and layer shapes), for pretty much all models, is not possible.

Now, assuming you do - still - have access to `net`. My advice is that work with `net.state_dict()` directly, modify it, then load the dictionary of weights back with [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict). This way, you will avoid having to deal with serializing the model's parameters yourself.

Comment: Sir, I need serialized weight vector of the entire net to perform some mathematical manipulations. I am a beginner in PyTorch so can you please give some examples? Thank you.